# Laravel remembering users

Tags: laravel-5.1

I didn't touch anything in the Laravel's registration, I just implemented basic login/register functionality and I created a route to activate users by email, like so. But I couldn't find how to login a user with remember me functionality after activated his account.

My route

```
Route::get('auth/activate/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@activate');
```

PasswordController

```
public function activate($token) {
    //get token value.
    // find the user that belongs to that token.
    $activation = User::where("confirmation_code", $token)->get()->first();
    // activate user account
    $activation->confirmed = 1;
    $activation->save();
    Auth::loginUsingId($activation->id); // User is logged in now.
    return view("frontend.feed.index");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method loginUsingId looks like this:

```
Authenticatable loginUsingId(mixed $id, bool $remember = false)
```

So just add the optional parameter and set it to true.

```
Auth::loginUsingId($activation->id, true);
```

Comment: Aaaaand it's done. Thank you. I should've been more careful and looked into it. I'll accept it in 10 minutes.